# data integration services between java system and sql server

Tags: java, sql, xml, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am currently architecting some integration services for a web application. External java applications produce a data feed which supplies data, the data is massaged as necessary and then inputted in to a sql server database. The data is managed here and used as the basis for wcf and http rest services which are accessed by web applications, mobile devices etc.

This is the current setup. I am at present changing this modifying this as we have some issues with the integration of the java system and sql server database. The main issue we have is the standard of the data required, it can be missing fields etc. The current integration is a comma separated file placed on an ftp server, the file picked up, the file processed, data massaged and data inserted in to the sql server. Where we are currently getting "burned" is that data is inserted in to the sql server database and the quality of the data is not up to the necessary standard and/or quality.

So this process is being changed and looking for options as to both modernize this and make the integration services more robust.

So I am looking for both suggestions and recommendations to improve the above?

Some options that spring to mind are:

- Expose a wcf service that the java system calls, data gets passed to it via the SOAP protocol, data then validated in the service before inserting in to sql server
- Format of the data supplied moves from common separated file to an xml file and the xml file gets validated against a schema before the data is massaged

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your solutions is going to solve your data quality problem at its source.  I'd look more critically at the applications producing the data and put the validation there *in addition* to validating it before INSERT into the database.  You want to validate prior to INSERT, because you should never trust clients.  But clients ought to honor a contract when they send you data.

One advantage that the web service offers that the others don't is the possibility of real time INSERTs into the database.  Let the source applications send their requests to this broker service.  It validates requests and inserts them in real time.  No more batch.